# How to continue ranking across multiple sheets in excel

Tags: excel, rank

I have data across multiple sheets in excel 2007 (will shift to higher version later) for which I want to make a Search option, so I used another sheet to enter desired input which in turn searches across all sheets and displays result based on RANK which is set in each individual sheets.

Eg:

[image]

Now I have all sheets with their individual ranking, but i need to have continued ranking across all sheets, below is expected result:

[image]

I am using below formulas for Rank & Rating columns:

RANK => RANK(B3,$B$3:$B$65536,1)

RATING => SEARCH(Sheet4!$C$2, C3)+ROW()/100000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boy I feel stupid !!
Used **MAX** function to get earlier sheet number & added it to **RANK**